# How can i print '\' in python?

Tags: python, printing, backslash

Is there any way to print back slash in python? we can write a string in three format.
1. ASCII
2. Unicode
3. Raw String

I have tried with all 3 formats but not able to get expected result. 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Using a raw string to print only a backslash will fail spectacularly due to how Python parses strings.

Answer (score 3):

Use double backslash, first one marks the escape character:

```
print("\\")
```

Answer (score 0):

**First option - Unicode**:

```
print('\u005c')
```

**Second option**:

```
print('\\')
```